# Why is a Werewolf not immune to Sanguinare Vampiris?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

After achieving Level 30 (+/-) in Skyrim, I installed the Dawnguard DLC and surprisingly in one of the Vampires' invasions (in Markarth, if I'm not wrong) I contracted Sanguinare Vampiris from a Volkihar Vampire, which shouldn't be possible as I am a Werewolf.

I would like to know why or how this happened.
Isn't a werewolf immune to diseases because of the beast blood?

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness: I appreciate your time reviewing the question but you cut too much data apparently irrelevant, changed the subject and now the question do not make much sense without the full context.

Comment: @Ender: I appreciate your second review but I think the fact I probably contract the disease from a Volkihar Vampire, which is more... powerful than regular vampires and this clan is only available from Dawnguard still relevant.

Comment: I've never played the DLC so I was unaware of the special nature of this vampire. In the future, you should have the power to 'rollback' edits you disagree with, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: No problem. I kept the revisions made in order to no go against any of the rules.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto It's not against any rules to rollback or improve edits in order to (re)clarify things. The thing discouraged by the rules is participating in an edit war, i.e. `A` edits, `B` rolls back, `A` does the same edit again etc - should you ever stumble into one of these it's best to leave a comment and flag for moderator attention. This is of course not the case here, Ender and you have converged this into a good understandable question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously this is a bug, since Werewolves are immune to diseases because of Beast Blood.

And although Sanguinare Vampiris can be contracted even while possessing the Beast Blood, as much as I could test, the disease does not progress to Vampirism as stated in Active Effects.

However, until cured, you keep the single negative effect:  Health reduced by 25 points, which is not a big deal after level 50 (even on Legendary).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you keep the latest savegame before that contraction!

The uesp wiki states the following:

> [You can also cure your vampirism by becoming a werewolf through the Companions faction. However, once you contract lycanthropy, you gain a 100% resistance to disease and cannot be re-infected with Sanguinare Vampiris by normal means while a werewolf.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vampirism#Curing_Vampirism)

and

> [The first time you transform using Beast Form, you will immediately be cured of all diseases, including any stage of vampirism. This means you cannot be a vampire and a werewolf at the same time. The Beast Form power also automatically removes all of your equipment, and all summoned creatures (including dead thralls) will immediately die.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lycanthropy#Beast_Form)

but

> [Accepting Lord Harkon's gift of vampirism during the Awakening quest or asking Serana to make you a vampire (either during the Chasing Echoes quest or after the end of the Dawnguard questline) will also cure you of lycanthropy.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lycanthropy#Curing_Lycanthropy)

So there are about three possibilities:

- You will be cured of vampirism when turning into beast form, without ever becoming an actual vampire
- Volkihar vampirism is indeed stronger than lycanthropy and you are actually no longer a werewolf
- By a bug similar to

> [If a non-werewolf contracts Sanguinare Vampiris but has not become a vampire yet, becoming a werewolf will not cure vampirism. This will progress to the player being both vampire and werewolf at the same time. Since the werewolf feeding ability overrides that of the vampire, the player cannot feed as a vampire and there will be no way to prevent progressing to stage four vampirism.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lycanthropy#Bugs)

you have successfully managed to become a Wermpire / Vampilf...

Comment: I don't know if other comentees can see the Revision History but I said, before edited, I'm a werewolf not to play as werewolf, but only to not be a Vampire because it's annoying and in Legendary Mode, dangerous. That said, I almost never use the Beast Form power and had never fed while in werewolf form. That may be the reason: A "diluted" werewolf.

Comment: Yes that sounds reasonable. Did you try turning into beast form and than simply rest until it ended, to see whether that makes vampirism vanish?

Comment: I stated below, as much as I could test you don't become a Vampire when already a Werewolf. You keep the disease until healed by a priest, a shrine or by using a potion, but it do not progress to Vampirism anyway.

Comment: This bug happened to me and is very annoying. I was a werewolf before installing the expansions. Afterwards I contracted the vampire disease and 3 days later became a Vampire. I could not feed and thankfully had a back-up save.

Answer (score 0):

Going through this myself, currently have a 30% weakness to fire, fry like a  ginger in the sun and have the vampire seduction and vampire servant powers along with beast form. I was able to negate the effects of the sun inbetween loading screens with cure disease potions but it didn't remove the vampire crap. Sanguire vampiris is not listed in the active effects, however nightwalker's footsteps and the weakness to fire are sadly present. none of the shrines helped, or any normal logic of dealing with a glitch. my next attempt will be to go from werewolf to vampire lord and back to werewolf. see if that takes care of it. The negative effects showed up right after the dawnguard assualt on castle volkihar. So it either happened during the fight with harkon, or when i asked serana for the bloodcursed elven arrows. Other then that its a mystery to me. annoying glitch for sure

Comment: This doesn't really explain why it happens, I don't think